# Docker Postgres Liquibase

Tags: postgresql, docker, liquibase

Trying to find a solution for devs on our environment. I was looking for a way to run Postgres on a docker container with liquibase, pointing to a changelog file outside of the container and just couldn't find a solution. Was looking for some or be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to map to a file outside the container, you should use docker volumes: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Using the volumes you can map the external changelog folder to a docker-internal folder.

Answer (score 0):

A read-only bind mount is what you need:

```
docker run .. --mount type=bind,source=/host/path/to/changelog,target=/container/path/to/changelog,readonly ..
```